# passing data to controller

Tags: magento2, forms

I am passing data **from** below sample .phtml file to controller:

```
<form name="sendsms" action="<?php $params = [];
echo $block->getUrl("admin_sms/Sendsms/SendSMS", $params); ?>" method="POST">
    Mobile Number: <input class="input-text admin__control__text" type="text" name="mobile_number"><br>
    Message Body :<textarea class="input-text admin__control__text" name="message_body"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send_sms" class="ui-button-text" value="send SMS"><br>
</form>
```

Below is a **controller**:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\module_name\Controller\Adminhtml\Sendsms;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class SendSMS extends Action
{
    protected $_resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Forward to edit
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "execute";
        die();
    }
}
```

Block file contains below **`getUrl`** function:

```
public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
{
    return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

When I am trying to submit form, it keep getting redirected to dashboard in admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid declaring the `$params` array inside the action of `<form>` tag.

Also use `$this->getUrl()` instead of `$block->getUrl()`

Try this instead

```
<?php 
$params = [];
<form name="sendsms" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("admin_sms/Sendsms/SendSMS",$params);?>" method="POST">
Mobile Number: <input class="input-text admin__control__text" type="text" name="mobile_number" /><br/>
Message Body :<textarea  class="input-text admin__control__text" name="message_body"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="send_sms" class="ui-button-text" value="send SMS"/><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, it was issue with $params array declaration inside form action, making changes as per your answer solved this problem.